# Getting an error in the program called java.util.InputMismatchException why? And how do we fix this?

Tags: java, delimiter

The program is about an ATM Transaction Validator. I'm suppose to have an output in a file called statement.txt and read in a file called transaction.txt.

I must have

- customers last name, followed by a comma as a delimiter.
- checking account balance.
- transaction type code.
- transaction amount.

Transaction type codes, W - Withdraw, D - Deposit, R- Report the balance.

I will not paste the statement.txt, because there is nothing there, its empty blank since the program won't compile properly.

Below you will see the codes here.

Here is the ATM output:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class ATM {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name; 
        double transamount, D, W, X;
        double balance;
        char symbol = '$', transtype, transactiontypes, amountsufficent;
        int instructions = 0;

        Scanner kb = null; 
        PrintWriter pw = null; 
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null; 

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream("transactions.txt");
            fos = new FileOutputStream("statements.txt");
            kb = new Scanner(fis);
            pw = new PrintWriter(fos);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not Found");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        kb = new Scanner (fis);
        pw = new PrintWriter(fos);
        {
      // while(kb.hasNext());
        {
       kb.useDelimiter(",");
        name = kb.next();
        String[] names = name.split(" ");
        pw.printf("Customer Name: " + (names[1] +", "+ names[0]) + "\n");
        System.out.println("Customer Name: " + names[1] +", "+ names[0]);
        //kb.next();
        // kb.reset();//

        balance = kb.nextDouble();
        pw.printf("Checking balance before transaction $ %.2f", + (balance));
        pw.print("\n");
        System.out.format("Checking balance before transaction $ %.2f%n",balance);

        transtype = kb.next().charAt(0);
        pw.println("Transaction type: " + transtype);
        System.out.println("Transaction type: " + transtype);

        transamount = kb.nextDouble();
        pw.printf("Transaction amount    $ %.2f", + (transamount));
        pw.print("\n");
        System.out.format("Transaction amount $ %.2f%n", transamount);

        D = balance + transamount;
        if(transamount>0) {
             W = balance - transamount;
        } else {
            W=balance;
        }
        switch(transtype){
        case 'D':  pw.printf("Checking balance after transaction  $ %.2f", + (D));
                   pw.print("\n");
                    System.out.printf("Checking balance after transaction  $ %.2f%n", + (D));
                    if(D<300){
                   pw.println("Warning: account is below $300");
                    System.out.println("Warning: account is below $300");
                    }
                    break;
        case 'W':  pw.printf("Checking balance after transaction  $ %.2f", + (W));
                   pw.print("\n");
                   System.out.printf("Checking balance after transaction  $ %.2f%n", + (W));
                   if (W < 300)
                   {
                   pw.println("Warning: account is below $300");
                    System.out.println("Warning: account is below $300"); 
                    }
                   break;
        case 'R':  pw.printf("Checking balance after transaction  $ %.2f", + (balance));
                   pw.print("\n");
                   System.out.printf("Checking balance after transaction  $ %.2f%n", + (balance));
                   break;
        case 'X':  pw.println("Error: Invalid Transaction Type");
                   System.out.printf("Error: Invalid Transaction Type" + "\n"); break;
        }
        if (transamount < 0)
        {
                   pw.println("Error: Negative amount cannot be entered");
                   System.out.println("Error: Negative amount cannot be entered");
        }
        switch (instructions)
        {
        case 'B':  pw.println("Checking balance before transaction"); break;
        case 'W':  pw.println("Checking balance after transaction "); break;
        case 'D':  pw.println("Deposit"); break;
        case 'R':  pw.println(" ");break;
        case 'X' : pw.println("invalid");break;
        default:  break;
        }
        kb.nextLine();
        pw.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
//      }


        kb.close();
        pw.close();
    }}}}





  And the transaction.txt code, 

     Joe Turker, 4124.50 D 200
    Charles Renee, 300.00 D 100
    Sam Back, 350.25 W 51 
    Sam Miller, 600.50 X 600
    Robert McCarthy, 1000.00 R 0 
    Jack Atanasoff, 200.00 W 200
    Anne Stroustrup, 300.75 W 300 
    Amanda Hollaway, 500.00 W -2
```

Every time I'm running the ATM class, it's showing this error:

```
Customer Name: Turker, Joe
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
    at ATM.main(ATM.java:46)
```

Exactly what is that and how to not get that again? The code did work about a few weeks ago, but does not work anymore, but not sure how this happened.

Thanks for responding!

Comment: I would suggest you begin by reading the file one line at a time, then you can `split` to *parse* a line. Additionally, your code could be simplified tremendously.

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the full error. It should show the line number in which you are getting this error. Also, the transactions.txt is most likely the problem. Your code is expecting a double where there is a string or something like that. So if you post the transactions.txt, and the full error I would be happy to give you more help.

Comment: That's what I was assuming. I have went back and edited the post. I meant to say, the transactions.txt is the file that contains the writing/names, which will display in the statements.txt, which is empty. I'm not sure why now. Thanks for the help again.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner uses spaces as delimiters by default, told it to use a comma *instead*, not in addition to.  Therefore, the first line

```
Joe Turker, 4124.50 D 200
```

was being read as

```
Joe Turker  
 4124.50 D 200
```

`nextDouble` was being fed `4124.50 D 200`, which is the reason for your mismatch exception.  You can use multiple delimiters by feeding the useDelimiter method a regex.

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(fis).useDelimiter("[\\s|,]+");
```

Answer (score 0):

**The reason you are getting this exception** - The second token returned is not a double alone but " 4124.50 D 200"

**How to resolve it** - So one option is you may want use a scanner on the second token and get the data:

```
    kb.useDelimiter(",");
    name = kb.next();
    System.out.println("Name : " + name);
    String[] names = name.split(" ");
    System.out.println("Customer Name: " + (names[1] +", "+ names[0]) + "\n");
    //kb.next();
    // kb.reset();//
    Scanner kb1 = new Scanner(kb.next());
    balance = kb1.nextDouble();
    System.out.format("Checking balance before transaction $ %.2f", + (balance));
    System.out.format("Checking balance before transaction $ %.2f%n",balance);

    transtype = kb1.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println("Transaction type: " + transtype);
    System.out.println("Transaction type: " + transtype);

    transamount = kb1.nextDouble();
    System.out.format("Transaction amount    $ %.2f", + (transamount));
    System.out.format("Transaction amount $ %.2f%n", transamount);
```

Would like to see if we can solve with a single Scanner, may be, by doing some regex changes for delimiter.